# Percolation universality class

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, renormalization, conformal-field-theory, percolation

There's very good table of different universality classes:

[image]

Ising model lies in the same universality class with $\phi^4$ theory.
Ising in $d≥4$ have critical exponents for free scalar field.

But I don't know field theories, which belong the percolation universality class. So I have few questions:

1. Which field theories belong in **percolation universality classes**?
2. What is **percolation CFT**?
3. What is field theory, that have **"mean field" values for percolation universality class** in $d≥6$?

Comment: The links in the Wikipedia redirect to the realisation of percolation universality class in description of some liquid crystals. Moreover, in the series of papers by Olesen and Ambjorn, they proposed a confinement mechanism, as a chaotic system of vortices, and at the phase transition there was a description in terms of percolating clusters. However, as I far as I understand, such a picture doesn't completely agree with the experimental evidence and Lattice QCD

Comment: @spiridon_the_sun_rotator, thank you. But my question about field theory realization of this universality class.

Comment: This seems to be a good review article: https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0409670